# How to call GetStdHandle, GetConsoleMode from Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, pinvoke

I'm getting error when trying to read the current Windows console mode from a Powershell script using [the `Add-Type` approach](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/25/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/):

```
$MethodDefinitions = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);
'@
$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinitions -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru
$hConsoleHandle = $Kernel32::GetStdHandle(-11) # STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE 
$lpMode = 0
$Kernel32::GetConsoleMode($hConsoleHandle, $lpMode)
```

But I get the following warning and errors:

```
WARNING: The generated type defines no public methods or properties.
Method invocation failed because [Win32.Kernel32] does not contain a method named 'GetStdHandle'.
At C:\Users\John\get_console_mode.ps1:8 char:1
+ $hConsoleHandle = $Kernel32::GetStdHandle(-11) # STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [Win32.Kernel32] does not contain a method named 'GetConsoleMode'.
At C:\Users\John\get_console_mode.ps1:10 char:1
+ $Kernel32::GetConsoleMode($hConsoleHandle, $lpMode)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: As per the accepted answer, here is the corrected code:

```
$MethodDefinitions = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);
'@
$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinitions -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru
$hConsoleHandle = $Kernel32::GetStdHandle(-11) # STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE 
$mode = 0
$Kernel32::GetConsoleMode($hConsoleHandle, [ref]$mode)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it with the following method definitions (I just added the public access modifier)

```
$MethodDefinitions = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);
'@
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I also needed `[ref]` before the second argument when calling `$Kernel32::GetConsoleMode`

Answer (score 1):

I’ll supplement the solution here with this example.

Each person can then implement the transfer of parameters in their own way, for example, transfer a mode name , and also set
disable/enable/inverse/check

```
$MethodDefinitions = @'
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint lpMode);

  public const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE  = -10;
  public const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;

  public const int  ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT            = 0x0001;
  public const int  ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT            = 0x0001;
  '@

  $WinAPI = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinitions -Name 'WinAPI' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru
  $hConsoleHandle = $WinAPI::GetStdHandle($WinAPI::STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
  $mode=$WinAPI::ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT
  $WinAPI::GetConsoleMode($hConsoleHandle, [ref]$mode)

  if($true){
      # disable
      $dmi = -bnot $WinAPI::ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT
      $mode = $mode -band $dmi
  } else {
      #enable
      $dmi = $WinAPI::ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT
      $mode = $mode -bor $dmi
  }
  # inversion - enabled or disabled
  # $mode = $mode -bxor $WinAPI::ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT  

  # check 
  $mode -eq ($mode -bor $WinAPI::ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT) 

  $WinAPI::SetConsoleMode($hConsoleHandle, $mode)
```