# PowerShell: close stdout handle

Tags: powershell, stdout

The task is to close the stdout handle a while before the process exits. With WinAPI functions, it'd be this:

```c
CloseHandle(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE))
```

I know I can do [`DllImport` with `Add-Type`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38045245/1833960) but I believe there must be a nicer way.

What's the simplest way to accomplish the same with PowerShell?

The wider task is to test a piece of a Python library that starts and interacts flexibly with local (with help of `subprocess` and `_winapi` modules) or remote (via WinRM) processes on Windows. One of the tests is to run a program that closes its ends of stdout and stderr pipes a while before it exits. (There was a similar issue on Linux.) Therefore, a script must closes stdout and stderr so that the calling code is signalled by the OS that they're closed. The only way I found is to call `CloseHandle` on stdout and stderr handles. Calling `.Close` or `.Dispose` on the stream objects doesn't help: they seem to be closed only internally to the called process. The script should be in some "native" language that needs no additional compilers and interpreters. Therefore, it's either cmd, VBScript or PowerShell. Only the last one is able to call WinAPI functions. (At the moment of this update I already wrote scripts both on Python, which works perfectly but needs an interpreter to be installed, and Powershell, which works without any additional installations but a bit cumbersome and very slow.)

Comment: What problem are you solving?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I answered in the question.

Comment: So, did you ever find an answer, @GeorgeSovetov?

Comment: @CaptainFim nothing, unfortunately.