# How to make Windows API calls return their value when called through PowerShell/C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi

I am trying to use C# code to bind Windows API calls to PowerShell commands. So far, I have determined that my calls to `GetStdHandle` in PowerShell are not returning the value that `GetStdHandle` returns. How can I make them do this? The PowerShell code and the C# code it generates are shown below.

```
#Accessing the Windows API
#Helper functions
$script:nativeMethods = @();
function Register-NativeMethod([string]$dll, [string]$methodSignature)
{
    $script:nativeMethods += [PSCustomObject]@{ Dll = $dll; Signature = $methodSignature}
}

function Add-NativeMethods()
{
    $nativeMethodsCode = $script:NativeMethods | % { "
    [DllImport(`"$($_.Dll)`")]
    public static extern $($_.Signature);
" }
    #echo $nativeMethodsCode

    $finalCode = "using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public static class NativeMethods
{
    $nativeMethodsCode
}"

echo $finalCode
    Add-Type @"
$finalCode
"@
}

#Add API calls here
Register-NativeMethod "kernel32.dll" "bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hWnd, int dwMode)"
Register-NativeMethod "kernel32.dll" "bool GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle)"
#Build and register the class
Add-NativeMethods
```

The C#code it generates:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hWnd, int dwMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
    public static extern bool GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
}
```

When I run this PowerShell command to call the API command `GetStdHandle`, the value that it returns is a boolean `True`, not an actual handle. How can I make it return the value returned by `GetStdHandle`?

This is the command I use to call `GetStdHandle` from PowerShell:

```
PS > [nativeMethods]::GetStdHandle(-11)  #Should return a handle to the current console
True
PS >
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045245

Comment: It returns an IntPtr not a bool. (Actually a handle, but you have to use an IntPtr because C# doesn't know handles per se.)

Comment: @Robert Harvey thank you! Looks like it was a simple misunderstanding of C# on my end. I was declaring the C# method for `GetStdHandle` to return a bool.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Robert Harvey for pointing me to another question about this. My invocation of `Register-NativeMethod "kernel32.dll" "bool GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle)"` should have used `IntPtr` instead of `bool`.